# Not enough space for upgrade error ( even though space is available)(14.10)

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 (64 bit) alongside windows 7 (In a different partition). The partition ubuntu is installed is 60 GB in size. When I tried to upgrade to 15.04 version, I had an error saing that not enough free space was available.

I want to know how to solve this error.I could not find any other question similar to mine.I have also attached a screenshot of the error.(Since I am a new user, well explained steps will be appreciated). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Screenshot? Could you please post/edit your post with the output of the following? `df -h` ? Maybe you/we will spot the issue then.

Comment: @Sinn3d Can u tell me how to paste the output? It says I should have a reputation of above 10 to add images.